# Navigation Hover Effect with CSS

Tags: css, navigation, css-float, padding, margins

I'm trying to achieve a hover effect with a background with the menu items, but with the css I have things appear to be out of place. I've tried many different things and still can't figure out how to have the menu items stay in place when on hover, and also not to have the text stick to the bottom on top of background.

http://youvisit.com/creative/FindYourFutureCampaign/html/

Comment: You should provide a full example, with code, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by adding your left/right images (the ones with the rounded corners), you're changing the width and height of the `<li>`. Since those images are 19px tall, you need to get the height of the `<li>` to be 19px. You can do this using `line-height` and `height`. After doing that, you'll have to figure out how to vertically align the text in the `<a>`. Then, you need to adjust for the changes in width. You could do this by using left/right padding on the `<a>`, and then remove that padding on hover (the padding removed should equal the width of the left/right image).

This should get your pretty close. I didn't test this in IE7/8.

```
ul.menuItems li {
    float: left;
    height: 19px;
    line-height: 19px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
ul.menuItems li a {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 19px;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding: 0 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menuItems li:hover a {
    background: url("../img/menuHoverCenter.png") repeat-x 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.menuItems li:hover:before {
    content: url("../img/menuHoverLeft.png");
    float: left;
}
ul.menuItems li:hover:after {
    content: url("../img/menuHoverRight.png");
    float: right;
}
```

Really, this is a bad design. You probably don't need to add content on hover. How about using CSS3 `border-radius` to get your rounded corners. Then use either `linear-gradient` or a background image for your background. `border-radius` is not supported by all browsers, but it's fairly well supported if you're not worried about IE8 and lower: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Comment: Yeah I realized css3 would be a easy solution alternative to using images as backgrounds, but the problems is my boss will want to make sure the schools administrators are able to see the same design as in modern browsers and a majority of them are still using lower versions of IE.... :(

Comment: Well, I'll modify my answer to include some of the CSS you'll need to do it how you're trying to.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer (see above). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like magic. I checked that it also works in IE9 I guess that's good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix your css and it will not "jump":

```
ul.menuItems li:hover:before {
    background: url("../img/menuHoverLeft.png") no-repeat 50% 0%;
}
ul.menuItems li:hover:after {
    background: url("../img/menuHoverRight.png") no-repeat 50% 100%;
}
```

And give `height` with `width` to work properly.

Comment: This doesn't work. Content adds inline content to the element. Also, `content` doesn't support `background` properties. It seems you've confused the two.

Comment: Giving a width and a height will help solve the problem, but you still cannot have `no-repeat` and positioning in `content`. This is incorrect.